# How do I replace the value of a variable from the same H1 element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

In my webpage, I have a dropdown selection where every time an item from the list is selected, it becomes the first-child of that list. From there, an H1 element is created, where this first-child (stored in the variable 'drink') is added to the H1 element, reading "drink.text()? Great Choice." However, when the user wants to change their selection, changing the first-child of the list, I want to change the variable 'drink' from the same original H1.

Code:

```js
console.clear();

var el = {};

$('.placeholder').on('click', function(ev) {
  $('.placeholder').css('opacity', '0');
  $('.list__ul').toggle();
});

$('.list__ul a').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var index = $(this).parent().index();

  $('.placeholder').text($(this).text()).css('opacity', '1');

  console.log($('.list__ul').find('li').eq(index).html());

  $('.list__ul').find('li').eq(index).prependTo('.list__ul');
  $('.list__ul').toggle();


  var drink = $('.list__ul li:first-child');

  var h = document.createElement("H1");
  h.classList.add("dranks");
  var t = document.createTextNode(drink.text() + '? Great Choice.');
  h.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(h);

  $(".dranks").html(drink.text() + '? Great Choice.');


});


$('select').on('change', function(e) {

  // Set text on placeholder hidden element
  $('.placeholder').text(this.value);
  // Animate select width as placeholder
  $(this).animate({
    width: $('.placeholder').width() + 'px'
  });

});
```

```css
.typo,
.list a {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #202530;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.typo option,
.list a option {
  font-size: 55px;
}

.transition {
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 150px;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.list ul {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.list ul .active {
  display: block;
}

.list li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.list li:first-child a {
  color: #e5b78e;
}

.list a {
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
  color: #e5b78e;
  position: relative;
}

.list a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #dea26e;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.list a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #dea26e;
}

.list a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  display: inline;
  border: 0;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #555;
  color: #e5b78e;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

select:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

select option {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5b78e;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

.placeholder {
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  color: #202530;
}

.placeholder:hover {
  color: #e5b78e;
}

.dranks {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper typo">today i'm feeling like a
  <div class="list"><span class="placeholder">select</span>
    <ul class="list__ul">
      <li><a href="">Flat White</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Long Black</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Cappuccino</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Mochaccino</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from my attempt, I have managed to do this somewhat, but I feel this is definitely not the correct way to do this. Any help on a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having? It looks like it correctly updates everything. What do you mean by "managed to do this somewhat"? Does it do what you want or not?

Comment: If it works but you think the style can be improved, that's more appropriate for [codereview.se]

Comment: it does work, but if you inspect element, you can see that each time you change the list, I believe what is happening is that all the previous h1's are changing and overlapping each other creating this hard edge on the H1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the `H1` already exists, and only create it if not.

```js
console.clear();

var el = {};

$('.placeholder').on('click', function(ev) {
  $('.placeholder').css('opacity', '0');
  $('.list__ul').toggle();
});

$('.list__ul a').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var index = $(this).parent().index();

  $('.placeholder').text($(this).text()).css('opacity', '1');

  console.log($('.list__ul').find('li').eq(index).html());

  $('.list__ul').find('li').eq(index).prependTo('.list__ul');
  $('.list__ul').toggle();


  var drink = $('.list__ul li:first-child');

  var h = $("h1.dranks");
  if (h.length == 0) {
    h = $("<h1>", {
      "class": "dranks"
      }).appendTo($('body'));
  }
  h.text(drink.text() + '? Great Choice.');


});


$('select').on('change', function(e) {

  // Set text on placeholder hidden element
  $('.placeholder').text(this.value);
  // Animate select width as placeholder
  $(this).animate({
    width: $('.placeholder').width() + 'px'
  });

});
```

```css
.typo,
.list a {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #202530;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.typo option,
.list a option {
  font-size: 55px;
}

.transition {
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 150px;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.list ul {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.list ul .active {
  display: block;
}

.list li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.list li:first-child a {
  color: #e5b78e;
}

.list a {
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
  color: #e5b78e;
  position: relative;
}

.list a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #dea26e;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.list a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #dea26e;
}

.list a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  display: inline;
  border: 0;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #555;
  color: #e5b78e;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

select:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

select option {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5b78e;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

.placeholder {
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  color: #202530;
}

.placeholder:hover {
  color: #e5b78e;
}

.dranks {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper typo">today i'm feeling like a
  <div class="list"><span class="placeholder">select</span>
    <ul class="list__ul">
      <li><a href="">Flat White</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Long Black</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Cappuccino</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Mochaccino</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```